# Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges. Exponential sequence and power sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this sequence:

$$a_n = \frac{4^n}{1 + 9^n}$$

How do I figure out if this diverges or converges? I tried using L'Hospital but that seems too complicated here. What else can I do?

Comment: You shouldn't piggyback additional questions to your original question, especially since the original question has been answered. Instead, you should ask a second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite this (dividing by $4^n$ on top and bottom) as
$$\frac1{\underbrace{4^{-n}}_{\to 0} + \underbrace{2.25^n}_{\to\infty}}$$

As $n\to\infty$, the first term in the denominator shrinks to zero and the other term grows without bound; so their sum grows without bound.

Since the denominator grows without bound and the numerator is a nonzero constant, the whole fraction shrinks to zero.

Answer (score 1):

It converges to $0$:

$$a_n=\frac{4^{-n}}{4^{-n}}a_n=\frac{1}{(1/4)^n+(9/4)^n}\to0$$

because $(1/4)^n\to 0$ and $(9/4)^n\to+\infty$ for $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

It converges and has limit $0$ because $a_n$ is non-negative and

$$
a_n \lt \frac{4^n}{9^n}=\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^n
$$
and the latter is a basic null sequence i.e. $\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^n \to0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For fun:

Let $n \ge 1$:

$0< \dfrac{4^n}{1+9^n} \lt \dfrac{4^n}{9^n} =\left (\dfrac{4}{9}\right )^n \lt  $

$\left (\dfrac{1}{2} \right )^n =\dfrac{1}{2^n} \lt \dfrac{1}{1+n} \lt \dfrac {1}{n}$.

The limit $n \rightarrow \infty$  is ?

Used: $2^n=(1+1)^n \gt 1+ n$ (Binomial expansion).